# Why a final field should be initialised when it is made nullable?

Tags: dart

```dart
class A {
  final int? b; // Error
}
```

Error:

> The final variable 'b' must be initialized.

Since the field `b` is nullable, it could be left uninitialised and hence needs no initialisation work. But it gives an error.

Comment: But it's declared as `final` still. final variables/fields must have an initializer. null-safe dart doesn't change this.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore But it could be `null`, right? So, why there is a need of initialisation when something can be `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not initializing a `final` field, regardless of whether it's nullable, is almost certainly a mistake.  This was not different before null safety was introduced.

Suppose that `final` fields were allowed to be implicitly initialized to `null`.  Then in a class such as:

```dart
class A {
  final int? b;
}
```

there would be no point for `b` to exist at all since it'd always be `null`.

But maybe `A` provides a constructor that could initialize `b` to a non-`null` value:

```dart
class A {
  final int? b;

  A();
  A.nonNull() : b = 42;
}
```

But now there's no way to tell if the default `A()` constructor actually wants `b` to be initialized to `null` or if the programmer just forgot to initialize it.  The latter is much more likely, so Dart errs on the side of requiring explicit initialization.

Comment: `There would be no point for b to exist at all since it'd always be null.` -- Even that was my initial thought too when I saw this sort of thing somewhere in the docs. (I'll get back to this later today).

Comment: Don't remember where I saw it. But sir `b` needs to be initialised in your code in `A()` as it is marked `final`.

Comment: Well, yes, `A()` needs to initialize `b` since it's marked `final`.  That's the whole point; your question asks why it needs to be initialized.

Comment: Yes sir, I got it. But still I don't remember where I saw something like `final int? b;` in the docs.

Comment: Are you thinking of https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator?  The `HttpResponse.ok` constructor does not initialize `error`, but I think that's probably a mistake.

Comment: At any rate, there's nothing *wrong* with using `final T? x`.  Sometimes you'd want a `final` variable that could be `null`.  It's the same behavior of variables from before null safety.

Comment: Yes, sir that's where I saw it in `HttpResponse.ok` and you can see that [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#nullability-and-generics) too. Pay attention to the 2nd code snippet where `Box.empty();` doesn't initialise the final field.

Comment: @iLoveDocs I filed https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/2586 to correct the docs.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -2):

You need to initialize b first like int b or string b; Assigning value is optional.

Comment: Sir what's `undefined` in Dart?

Comment: I am sorry i have updated the answer. I answer generically not specific to Dart.

Comment: Your answer is still very unclear, and it seems to be blatantly incorrect as well.

Comment: @RahulBeniwal What you actually want to say in your answer? Please read my question carefully before posting an answer.